# How to detect when person holds rope at the bottom part in a video, by applying computer vision methods?

Tags: computer-vision, object-detection

There is a video, where a person holds a rope at a specific moment.
What I would like to do is to understand when this person actually holding bottom rope automatically.
Can we do it with computer vision models?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, it is possible**

You should check out YOLO algorithm

Comment: YOLO is for object detection, but here, the problem is more about segmentation